# Copy file in GNU/Linux with progress bar and rate limiting

Tags: linux, file-management, cp, cpio

Is there any good tool in GNU/Linux that copy files like `cp`, but also shows progress and limits speed (and changes limit without interruption) like `pv`?

Prototype:

```
find source_directory | cpio -H newc -o | pv -s `du -bs source_directory/ | awk '{print $1}'` | (cd /destination/directory && cpio -di)
```

Also `rsync -aP source_directory /destionation/directory/`, but this shows progress bars individually and can't change rate after started.

Or may be I should just write a wrapper for pv/cpio? **Done.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Written the script to use find, cpio and pv to accomplish the task. The rate can be limited.

http://vi-server.org/vi/bin/cppv

Mirroring it here:

```
#!/bin/bash 

set -e

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "cppv - copy files with progress bar and rate limiting ability"
    echo "Usage: cppv source_file[s] destination_file_or_directory"
    echo "No other non-positional command line arguments can be given"
    echo "Always recurses like find"
    echo "You can change copying speed limit on the fly with \"pv -R\" if you find out pv's PID"
    echo "Use FIND_OPTS, PV_OPTS, CPIO_O_OPTS, CPIO_I_OPTS to override arguments to the pipeline parts"
    echo "Examples:"
    echo "    cppv a b # Copy file a to b. Just calls \"pv a > b\""
    echo "    cppv a d/ # Copy file a to d/a. Calls \"find a | cpio -o | pv | (cd d && cpio -i)\""
    echo "    cppv *{01..26}*.mkv /mnt/usb/ # Copy all matching files to /mnt/usb/."
    echo "    cppv dir1 dir2 # duplicate dir1"
    echo "    PV_OPTS=\"-L 1M\" cppv . /tmp/ # Limit copying rate to 1M"
    echo "    cppv /home/vi/bin /tmp/ # Warning: Copy /home/vi/bin to /tmp/home/vi/bin"
    exit 1
fi;

true ${CPIO_O_OPTS:="-H newc -0o"}
true ${CPIO_I_OPTS:="-0diu --no-absolute-filenames"}
true ${FIND_OPTS:="-depth -print0"}

ARGS=( "$@" );

DEST="${ARGS[$#-1]}"
unset ARGS[$#-1];

if [[ ( "${1:0:1}" == "-"  && ! -e "$1" ) || ( "${DEST:0:1}" == "-" && ! -e "$DEST" )  ]]; then
    echo "There should not be any command line options. Only file names." >&2
    exit 1;
fi

DIRMODE=0

if [[ $# > 2 || "${DEST:${#DEST}-1:1}" == "/" || -d $DEST ]]; then
    DIRMODE=1
elif [[ -d "$1" && ! -d "$2" ]]; then
    DIRMODE=1
    mkdir "$DEST";
    DEST=`readlink -f "$DEST"`;
    cd "$1";
    ARGS=(".")
fi

if [ $DIRMODE == 0 ]; then
    pv "$1" > "$2" && exit 0;
fi;

if [ ! -d "$DEST" ]; then
    echo Not a directory: "$DEST" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ "${1:0:1}" == "/" ]; then
    echo "Warning: it will do a bit different thing than usual cp" >&2
    echo "    For example, copying $1 to $DEST$1, not to $DEST/`basename $1`" >&2
fi

SIZE=`du -sb "${ARGS[@]}" | perl -ne '/^(\d+)/ and $q+=$1; END{print $q}'`

find "${ARGS[@]}" $FIND_OPTS | cpio $CPIO_O_OPTS | pv -s $SIZE $PV_OPTS | (cd "$DEST" && cpio $CPIO_I_OPTS)
```

Someone, please test it.

Comment: +1 for you! I'm afraid I can't get around to testing it but it look pretty promising! Nice work!

Comment: What is `pv`? Is that [Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)? (It's not installed on Ubuntu 10.04 by default, so I don't have it).

Comment: @Stefan Lasiewski Yes, it is. `apt-get install pv`

Comment: Note for users: the script fails on large (>2GB) files.

Comment: Yup ... `value file size 5266956288 out of allowed range 0..16777215`. How does one get around that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check this out: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/A_progress_bar_%28gauge_box%29#File_Copy_Progress_Bar_With_Dialog

It looks rather neat! =)

Comment: @dag729 You're welcome! ;)

Comment: "tt will increase every-time a file is copied to $DEST" - bad, I want it to work both for many small files and one big. And no rate limiting.

Comment: @Vi - perhaps you could adapt it a little? It's only an example on how to display a progress bar.

Comment: No, I've written the wrapper around "cpio | pv | cpio". Soon will publish it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gcp`. Should be available on Ubuntu.

Comment: Works (although handling of special files is lacking)

Comment: Installed fine on Ubuntu Oneric but gave me errors and crashed on a simple `gcp file destination`

Comment: No speed limiting option.